# How to work with recyclerview item IDs in Adapter class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have tried to solve this issue for the past three days but to no avail. I am retrieving data from two database tables joined together (Table names are "classes" and "Sections"). The problem are described by the images below.

[image]

[image]

Each school class (Grade one, Grade two etc) should display sections(Grade1A for Grade one class, Grade2A for Grade two class, etc) for each class that was clicked. But from the Image all classes show the same (class sections) irrespective of the class that was clicked.

**Question**

How do I make each Section to display for their respective classes?
A sample code will be very much appreciated. If there is a way to get the Id of the recyclerViewItem and match it with the Id of the class name in the classes table, I will appreciate a code sample thanks.

Here is what I did in the `onBindViewHolder()` of my Adapter class. I think the error is from here

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ClassSectionOnSetupRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolderCSOS holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView_classname_sections.setText(listClassesCSOS.get(position).getClasses_name());
    holder.layoutt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            // still thinking on how to apply this(this gets the ItemId of the recyclerview Items)
            long itemId = getRVItemId(position);  
            Log.i("itemId", String.valueOf(itemId));
            if (holder.expandableCardView.isShown()) {
                holder.expandableCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.expandableCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(itemId == listClassesCSOS.get(position).getId()) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    listClassesCSOS = demeaSQL.getAllSectionsByClassesID();
                    // not used yet
                    sectionsList = demeaSQL.getAllSections();
                     // getAllSections()
                    for (ClassesBean c : listClassesCSOS ){
                        sb.append(c.sectionBeanGetName() + "\n" + "\n");
                        // sets the textView with data from database after a class name has been clicked
                        holder.addedSectionTV.setText(sb.toString()); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    holder.add_class_section.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddSectionsDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use nested recyclerview or you can also use headers (section recyclerview )

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Santanu_Sur how does that work.  Am sorry for such question but I am new to this android stuff

Comment: @pskink yes I did

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

Comment: you can achieve this programatically but as you are new you can try this library..

Comment: The github Library? @Santanu_Sur

Comment: yes..they have a tut.. read that..

Comment: OK.  Would I need to create another adapter class different from what I have here while implementing the nested recyclelerView ? @Santanu_Sur

Answer (score 0):

in holder you calls `demeaSQL.getAllSectionsByClassesID();`. You don't set the `id` of class you have selected, therefore you receive same values by each class.

**UPDATE**

in your `demeaSQL` class you need new method `getAllSectionsByClassesID(long id)`

then change

```
listClassesCSOS = demeaSQL.getAllSectionsByClassesID();
```

to

```
listClassesCSOS = demeaSQL.getAllSectionsByClassesID(itemId);
```

Comment: Yeah I know @anatoli. How can I do this. I did not do it because I don't know the syntax on how to set the Ids for this.  Can u help me with a better implementation

Comment: if you call `listClassesCSOS.get(position)` in `onBindViewHolder`, you receive current class. This class object should have own id that you need to retrieve current class sections

Comment: Will the ID match the ID of Class name in the classes table of the database?  @anatoli

Comment: with `itemId` yu should be able to get current values for selected class

Comment: Please can you help me with syntax on its implementation. I have been trying it but doesn't work.  I will appreciate it.  Thanks @anatoli

Comment: I have tried your answer but it still shows up same sections for all classes. i.e it is not separated by id @anatoli

Comment: plase add our `getAllSectionsByClassesID(itemId)` method in question